# Getter/setter class in iOS Development

Tags: android, ios

I am looking to create an app I have already made for Android for iOS. I have a user class in the Android application, but I am not sure on how to do this for iOS. The class in android is as follows:

```
public class User {

    protected int score;

    public User() {
            score = 0;
    }

    public long getScore() {
            return score;
    }

    public User getScore(int score) {
            this.score = score;
            return this;
    }

    public int changeScore(int deltaScore) {
            this.score += deltaScore;

            return this.score;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you should start reading a book about Objective C to get a grasp of the basics... Just my humble opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch languages. You won't be able to use this exact same class in **iOS**. You will have an Objective-C class that will have a header that looks like this:

```
@interface User: NSObject {
    int score;
}
@property (assign) int score;
- (int) changeScore:(int)deltaScore;
@end
```

And a definition file that will look like:

```
@implementation User
@synthesize score
- (int) changeScore:(int)deltaScore
{
    self.score += deltaScore;
    return self.score;
}
@end
```

Comment: You can even omit the declaration of the score value (int score;) and use the property declaration only. The corresponding attributes will be generated by the compiler during build time.

Comment: don't forget the init method that sets score to zero initially.

Comment: Not strictly necessary;  all ivars in Objective-C are guaranteed to be set to 0 upon allocation of the instance.   However, still recommended to drop in a standard initializer and explicitly set the value to zero as a means of documenting intention.